# Get to a specific path from the the current directory path that I have in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I have my current directory path from the command `$PSScriptRoot`, suppose the path is

```
c:\abc\def\ghi\jkl\
```

now I want to go to the path

```
c:\abc\
```

so is there a command in powershell to go to that path directly???

Comment: What exactly is your goal? To got to a path that is 3 Folders up or go to a specific path?
Also what Version of Powershell are you actually using? Tagging 3 different versions isn't really what you should do..

Please take a look at [ask] and edit your question.

Comment: push-location c:\abc\

Comment: @Paxz I have a specific path from the command $PSScriptRoot(say c:\abc\def\ghi\jkl\ ), now i want to go to a folder which is in this  root path without hardcoding the whole path(say c:\abc\). by only passing the name of the folder( eg here we have the path c:\abc\def\ghi\jkl\  but i want to go to the folder "abc" by only passing the folder name and not giving the whole path of that folder)

Comment: @NBorah Then the answer offered by LotPings is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you actually want:

**1. Going to a specific Folder**

```
cd C:\abc\
```

**2. Going three level up**

```
cd ..\..\..\
```

You can also use `Set-Location` instead of `cd`.

Answer (score 1):

To extract the first level folder from `$PSScriptRoot` use a regular expression.
The RegEx `^(...[^\\]+).*$` builds a capture group with any first 3 chars (drive letter, colon and \)
and at least one non `\` char but as many as possible, so catching the first level folder.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\06\22\SO_5095782.ps1
"`$PsScriptRoot is {0}" -f $PSScriptRoot
if ($PSScriptRoot -Match '^(...[^\\]+).*$') {
    "First level folder is {0}" -f $Matches[1]
    Push-Location $Matches[1]
}
```

Sample output (I have a two line prompt with time and dir)

```
PoSh 12:44:10 Q:\Test\2018\06\22______________________
> .\SO_5095782.ps1
$PsScriptRoot is Q:\Test\2018\06\22
First level folder is Q:\Test
PoSh 12:44:15 Q:\Test_________________________________
```

**EDIT a stripped down variant and a version using sls/Select-String**

```
if ($PSScriptRoot -Match '^(...[^\\]+).*$'){PushD $Matches[1]}

$PSScriptRoot|sls '^(...[^\\]+).*$'|%{Pushd $_.Matches.Groups[1].Value}
```

Comment: I offered 3 variants all changing to the first level folder, what is the problem?

Comment: My motivation to help isn't pure altruism - there also is the reputation gained from checked marked answers and upvotes. So if you find my answer helpful you should [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)